# What's the port number for mongo db connection in telescope app?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, telescope

Currently I started to use open source Telescope app via meteor.

Also, I use Mongo db Compass to visualize my database.

But default 27017 port is not working with Telescope to connect and see my db.

Can you tell me what's the port number please ?

I used localhost and 2017, also tried to change 2017 to 3000, still not successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running meteor on port 3000, Mongo is on the next port, ie 3001, or if you are on port 4040, Mongo will be on port 4041